# How to implement the Facebook Api in Windows Universal apps?

Tags: c#, facebook, mvvm, facebook-sharer, win-universal-app

I'm trying to add functionality to allow sharing a screen shot of the app screen, using the `Facebook sharer` facility. But I can't find any relevant sources to set this up on `Windows Universal`.

Does anyone know the steps involved in setting up the `Facebook Api` in a Windows Universal application?

Or can you point me in the direction of a worthwhile link on the subject.

After logging into the FB developer dashboard, and clicking "getting started" , a screen showing the available platforms shows, not including Windows.

[image: get started FB]

I assumed that the correct option to pick would be "Website" , but as the setup process doesn't seem relevant to Windows Universal development, as setup asks for a website URL:

[image: web setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment, Facebook doesn't have an official SDK for Windows but you can use any of the open source alternatives.

I suggest you use the 'C SDK' library (http://facebooksdk.net/). I have never used it myself but it seems quite mature and popular.

Comment: In case anyone is looking for the specific example on publishing to feed, here it is http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/howtos/publish-to-feed/